# Python pandas json_normalize how to

Tags: python, json, pandas, transpose

I'm trying to create an API to get historical data from poloniex for my neuralnetwork to learn on for a school project.

I get a json file back but the problem is that the poloinex_df is "empty", all the information is in the index/columnnames row (pic realated, variable explorer), I tried to transpose it somehow, then I have been told here, that panda has a function for this. I read the documentation, and looked around here for anserws, but didn't quite found what i was looking for. i would like to make a dataframes with indexes like dates open close volumne etc. and the corresponding data. How do I do that? Right now I get the error:

```
data_frame = json_normalize(poloinex_df, 'date' ,['high', 'low', 'open', 'close','volume','quoteVolume','weightedAverage'])
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       data_frame = json_normalize(poloinex_df, 'date' ,['high', 'low', 'open', 'close','volume','quoteVolume','weightedAverage'])
>
> File "C:\ToolBox\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json.py",
>   line 761, in json_normalize
>       _recursive_extract(data, record_path, {}, level=0)
>
> File "C:\ToolBox\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json.py",
>   line 747, in _recursive_extract
>       recs = _pull_field(obj, path[0])
>
> File "C:\ToolBox\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json.py",
>   line 698, in _pull_field
>       result = result[spec]
>
> TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Pic in variable explorer from downloaded data:

[image]

I have to following code:

```
import chainer as chain
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pylab
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

def get_poloinex_data(s, a, b, c):

    import requests
    from pandas import DataFrame
    from io import StringIO

    url = 'https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnChartData'

    url += '&currencyPair=' + s #USDT for USD
    url += '&start=' + a
    url += '&end=' + b
    url += '&period=' + c

    csv = requests.get(url)

    if csv.ok:
        return DataFrame.from_csv(StringIO(csv.text), sep=',') #Separator here
    else:
        return None

params = {
    # specify stock
    "s": 'USDT_ETH',   # BTC_ETH, USDT_ETH stb

    # query data from
    'a': '1422230400',     # unix date stamp, 2015 jan 26 : 1422230400

    # query until
    'b': '1492905600',     # unix dates tamp, 2016 sep 23 : 1492905600

    # frequency
    'c': '14400'      # unix time stamp
}


poloinex_df = get_poloinex_data(**params)
data_frame = json_normalize(poloinex_df, 'date' ,['high', 'low', 'open', 'close','volume','quoteVolume','weightedAverage'])
#data_frame = json_normalize(poloinex_df.json())
#TransposedData = poloinex_df.transpose()
#data_frame = json_normalize(resp.json())
```

Thank you for your help and insight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

def get_poloinex_data(s, a, b, c):

    url = 'https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnChartData'

    url += '&currencyPair=' + s #USDT for USD
    url += '&start=' + a
    url += '&end=' + b
    url += '&period=' + c
    data = requests.get(url)

    return data.content

params = {
    # specify stock
    "s": 'USDT_ETH',   # BTC_ETH, USDT_ETH stb

    # query data from
    'a': '1422230400',     # unix date stamp, 2015 jan 26 : 1422230400

    # query until
    'b': '1492905600',     # unix dates tamp, 2016 sep 23 : 1492905600

    # frequency
    'c': '14400'      # unix time stamp
}

poloinex_df = get_poloinex_data(**params)
data_frame = pd.read_json(poloinex_df)
```